# Opting out of Scopus Author ID

Tags: privacy, scopus

The [Scopus Author Identifier](https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/11212/supporthub/scopus/) is an identifier that Elsevier attributes to researchers in order to create a public profile for them on its Scopus platform.

My question is whether researchers have successfully requested Elsevier to delete their identifier or profile on Scopus. Namely:

- Is Elsevier known to accept deletion requests? (I saw no documentation about this on their website.)
- Has there been any discussion of the status of such profiles relative to the EU [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation)? (One could argue in defense of Elsevier that the profile is compiled from public bibilographic metadata. That said, it contains personal identifiers (e.g., names), and it is not clear that publicly available personal data under GDPR can be freely reused, see e.g. [here](https://iapp.org/news/a/publicly-available-data-under-gdpr-main-considerations/).)
- Are there known cases of researchers who do not have a Scopus ID?

Answer (score 7):

Before getting to some of the specifics of your question, I think that one of your premises need to be addressed. The reason that the premise is important is that it has an effect on the potential legal implications for the Scopus Author Identifier (which I'll refer to simply as the SAID from here on).

You open by saying that the SAID exists "in order to create a public profile for them [authors] on its Scopus platform". That is not strictly correct.

[This page](https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/11212/supporthub/scopus/) at Elsevier explains that:

> The Scopus Author Identifier distinguishes among similar names by assigning each author in Scopus a unique number and grouping all of the documents written by that author,

and while it is true that it *can* be used in conjunction with a public "author profile", it originates as an numerical index in Elsevier's database of authors, not all of which is necessarily public.  Indeed, it would be unusual these days for any relational database not to have a numerical primary key of some kind, irrespective of the database language being used.

On [this website run by RMIT](https://rmit.libguides.com/c.php?g=677033&p=6588680), I saw confirmation of what I had suspected, namely that,

> Scopus Author ID is automatically generated if you have a paper in the database so registration for a Scopus Author ID is not required.

If there is a paper listed in the Scopus database, and the paper has authors, then each author will have a SAID. Of course, many authors have multiple different SAIDs. Why? Because in the case of those authors, Scopus does not have sufficient information to conclude that the different database entries all refer to the same individual.

Given that every author is necessarily associated with an identifier, one of your questions amounts to something along the lines of whether Scopus would agree to do either of the following:

1. Not show *any* identifier in conjunction with each appearance of your name on their public user interface; or alternatively
2. Agree deliberately to enter your name multiple times into their database so that each occurrence is associated with a unique identifier that is not linked to any of the other appearances of your name. In effect, this would be asking them to reverse what many authors do, which is to consolidate different author-database entries into a single entry that is, in turn, linked to all their publications.

I doubt that they would agree to doing this if they knew what your purpose was, but it is probably possible to mislead (!) them into believing that your name in association with "Paper 1" is not the same individual as the one referred to by the same name on "Paper 2". It sounds like a time-consuming process, but I wouldn't be surprised if it were possible.

Now to the provisions of the [General Data Protection Regulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) [of the EU](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:02016R0679-20160504&from=EN). The GDPR recognizes various different kinds of identifiers and controls their use. Some of the strongest protection is in Article 87, where the use of national identifiers of a kind such as the Social Security Number (in the US) or Tax File Number (in Italy) can be severely restricted by member states. On the other hand, Article 89, which governs "Safeguards and derogations relating to processing for archiving
purposes in the public interest, scientific or historical research
purposes or statistical purpose", would seem, on the face of it, not to prohibit the kind of activity in which Scopus is involved and for which it uses the SAID.

Lastly, it's worth considering Article 7, concerning "consent". If you had a paper published, and you put your name on it, and you did not (at the time) prohibit the journal from publishing your name, then one must assume that you consented to the use of your name in the contexts in which it you knew, or ought reasonably to have known, that it would be used. That doesn't *necessarily* extend to Scopus's use of the information (but see Article 89) but I can think of good arguments why it should (and, in any case, see Article 89).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I understand Elsevier wants to disambiguate authors, but they are still creating an identifier which they claim refers to me, and creating a public page based on that identifier. (I agree it would be different if this were not public, but it is.) Regarding consent, I don't think that publishing a paper means that I consented to have a page created for me with the list of papers I wrote along with various bibliometrics. In any case, thanks for your insights!

Comment: @a3nm isn't that stuff that most platforms do with a name, but they just did it with an ID number instead because some people have the same name? Wouldn't you *also* want them to remove your *name* because of the exact same privacy reasons?

Comment: @user253751 I'm not sure, since I'm not the OP, but I think the OP's concern is about Scopus identifying multiple papers by himself/herself as being authored by the same individual. Clearly difficult to avoid the inevitable inferences (even without a unique numerical identifier) if your name is WeAreAllIndividuals LifeOfBrian. But if your name is John Smith, you might want to hide among the thousands of other John Smith(s) on Scopus

Comment: Well, my concern is also about having a public profile created for me without my consent -- be it by name or by ID number. I don't know of many platforms which will do this -- when looking for my name on the internet, what I find is essentially accounts that I chose to create.

Comment: @a3nm If the exact same page was labeled "list of papers by a3nm" instead of "a3nm's profile" would it still be a problem?

Comment: Hm, I agree the line is blurry. I could understand that for a bibliographical database you could search by name, and that unavoidably there would be a page "Search results: papers by a3nm". My impression is that I perceive it differently when the page is called a profile, when it claims to have disambiguated (hence, authoritative) results, and when it is indexable by search engines. Note that Google Scholar, for instance, does things differently: you can of course search for papers by author name, but only authors who signed up for Google Scholar have a public profile listing their papers.