# Is it possible / how to delete "Elsevier Scopus" author data and public page?

Tags: elsevier, scopus

I do not like to be the product, and I like even less when a private company (in this specific case, Elsevier) makes a profit by exploiting my personal data and by providing a "paywalled profile / database" about me (in this case, the Elsevier / Scopus profile associated to me). Moreover, I already have a GoogleScholar profile (not that this is a perfect solution, but at least it is not paywalled and not as grossly "pay for viewing" / turning me into a "product").

Is there a way / how to get Elsevier Scopus to entirely remove "my" Elsevier Scopus public information and profile page from their system? What implications may this have for me?

Comment: Seems unlikely. Some information about you is public and free to use even if you don't like it. The reciprocal is true also. Some information about Elsevier is public and you are free to use it.

Comment: I live in the EU and fall under GDPR - is this really correct in this case, that some of my information is "public and free to use"? I think that information being public does not mean that it is free to re-use for commercial purpose without consent any more following GDPR?

Comment: Related: [Opting out of Scopus Author ID](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/193926/17254)

Comment: Agree it is related, but I do not think it is really the same - I do not want to opt out of their internal ID, they may keep one internally if they want, I just do not want them to make a commercial partially paywalled webpage making profit out of my information (public or private).

Comment: I'm not a lawyer and I don't know the details of GDPR, but if you publish something (literally make it public) then it is likely public.

Comment: Why not just contact Scopus and ask them? https://service.elsevier.com/app/contact/supporthub/scopuscontent/